# Unable to Run Hadoop Jar on Cloudera VM

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I've been given a Cloudera VM to use with learning Hadoop. I created a basic wordcount program in java and exported it to a jar file. I've tried to run the jar file but I'm getting this:

```
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

...
```

And it goes on until it gets to 10 times. I've never worked with Hadoop before so I'm pretty new and don't know what I'm doing with this. Any help is appreciated.

Some other information:

```
whereis hadoop

hadoop: /usr/bin/hadoop /etc/hadoop /usr/lib/hadoop /usr/share/man/man1/hadoop.1.gz
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
 </property>
```

Comment: try to `ps -ef | grep hadoop` to see if resource manager is running.

Comment: @fi11er I get a pretty long list of different things. Not entirely sure what I'm looking for

Comment: You are looking for resource manager, try `ps -ef | grep ResourceManager` to get more accurate result. If it is running, check if its port is open (`telnet 0.0.0.0 8032`). If it is not, try to restart RM, if this wouldn't help, your last hope is RM logs :)